# form field alignment with a table cell

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

Is there any way to horizontally centre the checkboxes in the following MWE? Also is there any way to adjust the size of the checkboxes so that (i) they do not touch the cell border, and (ii) they are vertically centred in the cell?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|c|}\hline
  1. & Floor Clear -- no trips & \CheckBox[print,name=1, width=1em, height=1em]{}\\\hline
   2. & Stairways -- no trips & \CheckBox[print,name=2, width=1em, height=1em]{}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [How do I make every CheckBox the same size?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9359)

Comment: @AlanMunn For example `\def\DefaultHeightofCheckBox{0.9ex}`
and `\def\DefaultWidthofCheckBox {0.9ex}`. Then omit setting the height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a partial solution. The dimensions of checkboxes are intentionally different, to see the alignment. Crucial commands, preventing from touching cell borders, are `\mbox` or `\hbox`. Attempt to centre verically is made by hand via `\rule`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|c|}\hline
%  1. & Floor Clear -- no trips & \CheckBox[print,name=1, width=1em, height=1em]{}\\\hline
1. & Floor Clear -- no trips &\mbox{\CheckBox[print,name=1, width=0.4em, height=0.4em]{}}\\\hline
%   2. & Stairways -- no trips & \CheckBox[print,name=2, width=1em, height=1em]{}\\\hline
  2. & Stairways -- no trips & \hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}}\\\hline
  3. & Stairways -- no trips &\rule[6pt]{0pt}{6pt}\hbox{\CheckBox[print,name=2, width=0.7em, height=0.7em]{}}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @azetina Thank you for an attempt, but the red {check) boxes have disappeared.

Comment: See updated image...:-) For some reason or the other sumatrapdf does not display those check boxes. Only Nitro pdf viewer did.