# Vertically aligning form fields within a table

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, multirow, forms

I would like to vertically align form fields within table rows. The problem I am facing is that other columns within the same row can stretch over multiple lines. Solutions as sketched in [form field alignment with a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142469/form-field-alignment-with-a-table-cell) thus do not work for me. The form fields should always be in the middle of the row, in independece of the row height.

Also, when I compile the code, the checkbox and the text field in row 2 are already placed at different vertical positions? Why is this the case?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}p{5cm} >{\centering}m{2.5cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}

    \hline
        \textbf{Descriptor} & \textbf{Checked} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \hline
    \endlastfoot

    % sample data
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliquyam erat, sed oluptua.
    & \CheckBox[name=ExampleCheck]{} 
    & \TextField[name=ExampleText]{} \\ \hline

    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
    Stet clita kasd gubergren.
    & \CheckBox[name=Example2Check]{}         
    & \TextField[name=Example2Text]{}

\end{longtable}
\end{Form}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use only `m`-type columns and remove unnecessary blank lines. Mixing the `m` and `p` column types can give inconsistent results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright}m{5cm} >{\centering}m{2.5cm} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Descriptor} & \textbf{Checked} & \textbf{Value} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    % sample data
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
    magna aliquyam erat, sed oluptua.
    & \CheckBox[name=ExampleCheck]{} 
    & \TextField[name=ExampleText]{} \\ \hline
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
    Stet clita kasd gubergren.
    & \CheckBox[name=Example2Check]{}         
    & \TextField[name=Example2Text]{}
\end{longtable}
\end{Form}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just realized that I forgot adapting the first column from p to m. I totally overlooked this. Thanks a lot. Although now I am feeling slightly embarrassed ;)