# Smaller hyperref check boxes

Tags: hyperref, height, forms

I have been using the hyperref package, and found that the check boxes have a certain minimum height. I was wondering if there would be a way to override this value, so I could make a small square checkbox. I've looked around in the hyperref documentation, but couldn't find anything relating to this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) node {
\CheckBox[backgroundcolor = , bordercolor = , 
height = 5pt, width = 5pt]{Check}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Your code does not work.

Comment: Does [How do I make every CheckBox the same size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9387/124842) solve your problem?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Yes, I am just now realizing that the font size sets the minimum height. Or, the height of another text field. So, I think I will have to place individual nodes at each location I want a check box. A bit annoying, but it should work.

Comment: Your code doesn't give me a checkbox at all.  I could get a checkbox by setting bordercolor and putting it in a Form environment.  Why not just use a tikz rectangle?

Comment: @JPi I was planning on placing a circle around each CheckBox, but the problem is there is now an ugly rectangle sticking out of the circle. I want to create a small square CheckBox field, so it fits nicely inside a circle.

Comment: You can still do that in tikz.