# Behaviour of CheckBox in hyperref package (heights differ)

Tags: hyperref, height

Coders,
i was playing with the hyperref package today and i noticed something odd.
Here is the MWE (not that minimal, but it shows the goal):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newsavebox\TBox

\title{Anamnesebogen}
\date{05.2023}
\author{Dr. N.N.}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={Anamnesebogen},
pdfsubject={Anamnese},
pdfauthor={Dr. med. N.N.},
pdftoolbar=false,
pdfmenubar=false
}

\def\DefaultTF{
print,
bordercolor={.04 .40 .44},
%backgroundcolor={.55 .85 .83},
backgroundcolor={},
borderstyle=U,
height=2.5ex, 
width=15em,
format={app.runtimeHighlight = false;}
}
\def\DefaultCB{
print,
width=1em,
height=0.9em,
bordercolor={.04 .40 .44},
backgroundcolor={},
borderstyle=S,
format={app.runtimeHighlight = false;}
}
\def\DatumTF{
format={AFDate_FormatEx("dd.mm.yyyy");},
keystroke={AFDate_KeystrokeEx("dd.mm.yyyy");}
}

\xdef\DefaultOptionsofText{\DefaultTF}
\xdef\DefaultOptionsofCheckBox{\DefaultCB}

\newcommand{\specialline}{\vskip\medskipamount % or other desired dimension
%\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt % or other desired thickness
\vskip\medskipamount % ditto
\nointerlineskip
}

\newcommand{\FormField}[1]{\sbox\Tbox{#1:\ }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\Tbox]{#1:\ }}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[width=6em, format={event.value=(new Date()).toString(); AFDate_FormatEx("dd.mm.yyyy");},
keystroke={AFDate_KeystrokeEx("dd.mm.yyyy");}]{Datum}\\[.7ex]
\sbox\TBox{Name }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Name}\\[.7ex]
\TextField[width=6em, format={AFDate_FormatEx("dd.mm.yyyy");},
keystroke={AFDate_KeystrokeEx("dd.mm.yyyy");}]{Geburtsdatum}\\[.7ex]
\sbox\TBox{Adresse }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Adresse}\\[.7ex]
\sbox\TBox{Mobilnr }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Mobilnr}\\[.7ex]
\sbox\TBox{E-Mail }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{E-Mail}\\[.7ex]
\sbox\TBox{Beruf }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Beruf}\\[.7ex]



\textbf{Beziehungsstatus} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Single}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Fester Partner}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Feste Partnerin}}


Hatten Sie Komplikationen während der Schwangerschaft/Geburt? \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=pregcomplno]{Nein}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=pregcomplyes]{Ja}}

\sbox\TBox{Wenn ja, welche? }\TextField[name=prefcompl,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Wenn ja, welche?}

\TextField[name=aborts, width=2em]{Wie viele Fehlgeburten hatten Sie?} \TextField[name=aussch, width=2em]{Wie viele Ausschabungen hatten Sie?} 

\specialline{}
\textbf{Familienplanung}

Haben Sie einen Kinderwunsch? \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=kinderwunschno]{Nein}} \quad{}   \mbox{\CheckBox[name=kinderwunschnow]{Jetzt}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=kinderwunschlater]{Später}}

Verhüten Sie? \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=vno]{Nein}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=vpill]{Pille}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=vcondom]{Kondom}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=vcopper]{Kupferspirale}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=vhormone]{Hormonspirale}}

\specialline{}

\textbf{Operationen}\\
\mbox{\CheckBox[name=geb]{Gebärmutter}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Gebärmutterhals}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Brust}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Eierstock}}\\
\sbox\TBox{andere OP }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{andere OP}

\specialline{}

\textbf{Krankheiten}\\
\mbox{\CheckBox{Diabetes}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Hoher Blutdruck}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Herzinfarkt/Schlaganfall}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Thrombose/Embolie}}\\
\mbox{\CheckBox{Depression/Erschöpfungssyndrom}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Migräne}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Autoimmunkrankheiten}}\\ 
\sbox\TBox{Wenn Autoimmunkrankheiten, welche? }\TextField[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Wenn Autoimmunkrankheiten, welche?}

\specialline{}

\sbox\TBox{\textbf{Medikamente/'Anti-Baby-Pille'} }\TextField[name=meds,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{\textbf{Medikamente/'Anti-Baby-Pille'}}\\
\mbox{\CheckBox[name=allergiemedsyes]{\textbf{Medikamente-Allergien}  Ja}} \quad{} \TextField[name=allergiemedstxt,width=10cm]{Welche?}

\specialline{}

\textbf{Familie} - Haben Geschwister/Eltern folgende Krankheiten:\\
\mbox{\CheckBox{Diabetes}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Herz-Kreislauf}} \quad{}  \mbox{\CheckBox{Brustkrebs}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Thrombose/Embolie}} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Sonstige}}\\
\sbox\TBox{Wenn Sonstige, welche? }\TextField[name=illothertxt,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\TBox]{Wenn Sonstige, welche?}

\specialline{}

\textbf{Mein Corona-Status} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox{Geimpft}}  \mbox{\CheckBox{Genesen}}

\textbf{HPV/Gebärmutterhals-Impfung} \quad{} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=hpvyes]{Ja}} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=hpvno]{Nein}} \mbox{\CheckBox[name=hpvmaybe]{Vielleicht}}

\specialline{}

\small
\TextField[name=recipes]{Meine Rezepte/Überweisungen etc. darf folgende Person abholen}

Hiermit willige ich ein, dass meine Daten DSGVO-konform gespeichert und weitergeleitet verschickt werden an: Krankenkasse, KV Nordrhein,  Labor/Pathologie:(Amedes), Philips Bildspeicherung, Doctolib Praxismanagement
\normalsize

\vspace*{3ex}
\TextField{Ort, Datum} \TextField[height=10mm]{Unterschrift}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

So the checkboxes differ in their size. Of course all of them have fixed height.

All Checkboxes who have text with "underlength" (?) like p,g are higher than the others with not so high characters.

Can I fix the behaviour? Of course, the checkboxes should be of the same height.

Best Wishes,
Peter

Comment: make a minimal example. I have neither the will nor the time to debug some non-minimal code.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9359/47927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand how the height of checkboxes is calculated, but it seems that is is affected by the height and depth of the characters in the label and the surrounding text in general.

Compare:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{ooo}

\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{boo}

\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{oog}

\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{bog}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

It has been noted that [all checkboxes in the same paragraph will get the same (maximum) height and depth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9387/47927). This behaviour can be overridden by [placing each checkbox in its own `\makebox` for example.

The [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf) tells us (in Chapter 9 "PDF and HTML forms") that the command `\LayoutCheckField` is used to typeset label and checkbox. It is defined as

```
\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
  \def\Hy@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\Hy@temp\@empty
    #2%
  \else
    #1 #2%
  \fi
}
```

Knowing that the height of the checkbox is affected by what is typed before it, we could put the checkbox into a `\makebox` to avoid that the surrounding text influences its height:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
  \def\Hy@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\Hy@temp\@empty
    \makebox{#2}%
  \else
    #1 \makebox{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{ooo}

\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{boo}

\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{oog}

\CheckBox[height=0.8em]{bog}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - maybe your adjustments to LayoutCheckField should be the default.